# MYSQL workbench - error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql

Now before you flag this as a duplicate, I went through many stack overflow solutions.

The names are matching

The data types match

Both are not null,

what could be the problem?

This is my code:

```
create database Registration;
use Registration;

create table Department(DepartmentID varchar(25) NOT NULL, DepartmentName varchar(25),
PRIMARY KEY(DepartmentID));
insert into Department(DepartmentID, DepartmentName) values ('DE1', 'Engligh');
insert into Department(DepartmentID, DepartmentName) values ('DS2', 'Science');
insert into Department(DepartmentID, DepartmentName) values ('DM3', 'Math');

create table Course(CourseID varchar(25), CourseName varchar(25), DepartmentID varchar(25) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (CourseID),
FOREIGN KEY(DepartmentID) REFERENCES Departmnet(DepartmentID));
```

Comment: typo in ...FOREIGN KEY(DepartmentID) REFERENCES Departmnet(DepartmentID));   departmnet

Answer (score 0):

```
create table Course(CourseID varchar(25), CourseName varchar(25),  DepartmentID varchar(25) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (CourseID),
FOREIGN KEY(DepartmentID) REFERENCES Department(DepartmentID));
```

You have made a spelling mistake on the table name DEPARTMENT in REFERENCES